# Run executable in context of a different exe by using a "wrapper" or "exe proxy"

Tags: c#, .net, dll, .net-assembly, code-injection

I have tried this

```
byte[] bytes = File.ReadAllBytes("Program.exe");
Assembly assembly = Assembly.Load(bytes);
assembly.EntryPoint.Invoke(null, new object[0]);
```

Compiles okay but when I run it, it says

> "Program not res..."

What im trying todo is run a dll without admin in the context of exeproxy.exe
Also somehow if this could be a function somehow that would be great. im change code to Visual c++

Im using the following

```
using System;
using System.IO;
using System.Reflection;

namespace exeproxy
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            if (args.Length == 0)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Usage: exeproxy <exe>");
                Environment.Exit(1);
            }
            string exe = args['0'];
            byte[] bytes = File.ReadAllBytes(exe);
            Assembly assembly = Assembly.Load(bytes);
            assembly.EntryPoint.Invoke(null, new object[] { new string[0] });
        }
    }
}
```

Useful link
http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/ajyadav123/executing-assembly-code-in-C-Sharp/

It may make more sense to use C++ or VC++ looking at the link for `asm()`.
You can use Calc.exe to test if it works; it's not all about running .net programs.

Comment: I've removed assembly tag as it's for the language not .net assembly

Comment: @PawełŁukasik : There is a `.net-assembly` tag that can be used.

Comment: @MichaelPetch thx, will add that next time

Answer (score 0):

You should change how you pass the parameters to the `EntryPoint`. The second parameter to invoke is an array of object that is resolved as the parameters to the Main. But `Main` takes a array of strings. So your call should be like this:

```
assembly.EntryPoint.Invoke(null, new object[] { new string[0] });
```

It works with a simple Program.exe that does printing to console. In case of a more complex program there might be more issues that needs to be handled.

Comment: For an program with an gui what issues are there?

Comment: well, I can see you've already used it. As I said - if you program hangs it might be of the reason that Program.exe is doing. And we can't know what is inside it.

Comment: as this seems to be hard for some programs i have made an github for it https://github.com/OfficialNoob/exeproxy

Comment: so does it solve your question/problem? if so - mark this as an answer to help others

Comment: Well im going to try to make it in Visual C++ as its got asm() also I looked at this http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/ajyadav123/executing-assembly-code-in-C-Sharp/  what you told me does not work for calc.exe so i do not know if your code works however i did put "this answer is useful"

Comment: Calc.exe is not a .net assembly. Why would you assume it should work?

Comment: Well thats what im trying todo whats the difference between .net assembly and "normal" assembly

Comment: `Process.Start("Calc.exe")`

Comment: Thats not running as exeproxy.exe